# Search Users satisfying search criteria

Tags: java, algorithm, design-patterns, database-design

I am working on project where users are registered with properties like age, skincolor, languages, height etc in SQL.

I want to provide search feature on registered users accepting range values. Example Search users between age between 15 to 20, who can speak English and French and skin color is Black. Also this request has to be stored in SQL.

One way to do this will be:
Provide request object which is constructed based on attribute being searched.
Like

```
searchUsersRequest : {
"age" : {
         "min" : 15
         "max" : 20
        },
 "languages" : [
          "English",
          "French"
        ],
 "skinColor" : [
           "Brown",
           "Black"
        ],
  .
  .
  .
  .
}
```

After reading the request, create query and run on db.

Here are two questions:

1. Is there any better way/ generic approach to solve this problem?
2. How should I stored this request object in DB? Should I just stored it as just one string or any other better way?

Thanks in advance for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

1) Let's pretend that you have a request object `SearchUsersRequest` with all the information needed in order to build your query.
This object can be "parsed" by a custom `FilterBuilder` that will build a raw query or a more complex `QueryFilter` if you are using an ORM.
Talking about a generic approach you can abstract the "search request" feautures into a custom class hieracy and use it in order to define specifc parameters for your FilterBuilder methdods.

2) Why you need to store it into the database? It's not a common approach. However if it is a mandatory requirement then you can use **json** o a sort of **xml** notation in order to keep object structure and **string** (or varchar) as database type. Then when you retrieve it from the database you have to parse it in order to build your request object back

Hope this could help you

Comment: Thanks Andrea! I'm too going with second approach till now.